# Export to Excel results in length of strings instead of data

Tags: excel, powershell, export

In PowerShell, I have a simple AD search routine that queries for a netbios name and returns the user name.
It's reading a text file of netbios names and adding to an array which at the end exports to Excel.
The Excel file only has integers in it, like the length of a string **instead** of the netbios and the username.
Here is a screenshot of the Excel output:
[Excel file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaImh.png)

Here is the code:

```
$de = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$ds = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$ds.SearchRoot = $de

Function GetInfo($argSearchCriteria) {
    $ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(samAccountName=$($argSearchCriteria)$))"
    $ds.SearchScope = "SubTree"

    $r = $ds.FindOne()

    if ($r.Count -ne 0) {
        
        $ReturningData = $argSearchCriteria.Trim()  + ",    " + $r.Properties.description.Trim()
        return $ReturningData

    } # end if

} # end function

$filename = "H:\Working\tags.txt"               # input text file, one netbios name on each line. i.e. ctb123456win10
$FilePath = $env:TEMP + '\' + 'AD_Report.csv'   # output CSV file containing netbios and username i.e. ctb123456win10, Smith Regan

# initialize new array for results
$FinalArray = @()

# open tag file and read each tag and get the user's name returned
$(foreach ($line in Get-Content $filename) {

    $Results = GetInfo ($line.trim())
    $FinalArray += $Results
    
    write-host $Results
 })

######   Export results to CSV file to be opened by Excel  #######
$FinalArray | Export-Csv -notype -Path $FilePath
            
# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
                
# Display Excel and Maximized it
$objExcel.Visible = $false

# Open the Excel file and save it in $WorkBook
$wb = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$range = $ws.UsedRange                  # select all values in workbook
$range.EntireColumn.Autofit()           # autosize all columns in selection
$ws.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold=$true         # bold the top header row
$ws.Rows("1:1").Interior.ColorIndex =48 # dark gray the top header row
$objExcel.Visible = $true               # display Excel
$objExcel.WindowState= "xlMaximized"    # max Excel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are piping an array of strings to `Export-Csv`. What you end up with is strings that look like:

```
 Server1,     Web Server
 Server2,     SQL Server
 Server3,     File Server
```

While what you want is object with two properties (NetBiosName and Description) like:

```
NetBiosName  Description
-----------  -----------
Server1      Web Server
Server2      SQL Server
Server3      File Server
```

Those objects you could pipe to `Export-Csv` and it would work as expected.

So you can either use `Set-Content` with what you presently have (though you would not have a header line like you expect to, and all of your descriptions would have several spaces at the beginning), or you can create objects to send to `Export-Csv`. I would suggest the latter.

Change your function to create objects:

```
Function GetInfo($argSearchCriteria) {
    $ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(samAccountName=$($argSearchCriteria)$))"
    $ds.SearchScope = "SubTree"

    $r = $ds.FindOne()

    if ($r.Count -ne 0) {
        
        [PSCustomObject]@{
          NetBiosName = $argSearchCriteria.Trim()
          Description = $r.Properties.description.Trim()
        }

    } # end if

} # end function
```

A function returns everything not explicitly redirected (such as things captured in a variable, or piped to something like `Write-Host`), so there's no need for the `return` line.